# Need to know more explanation about each and every xml elements for config.xml in module/etc/config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to know each and every xml elements (for which cases the elements can use) in module/etc/config.xml file
then only i can create the module based on my requirement.

Eg:

> global
>   models
>   blocks
>   adminhtml
>   rewrite
>   observers etc

Comment: http://theslidesareonline.de/magento-in-30-minutes-en.pdf. Starting with slide 74.

Comment: good share @Marius...

Comment: Is it possible to add a new fields in magento banner add/edit form page?...@Marius